# How to predicate objects inside array by object.name

Tags: ios, swift, predicate

I have object  Dog with variable

name : String , 
age :Int

I have [Dog] with 5 dogs there

I would like to predicate for searching bar which dog.name contain the input value

The code below failed , error said "no key name"

```
 let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF Any.name CONTAINS[c] %@", text)
    let array = (data as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
    let productSearchResults = array
```

Comment: Do you really need NSPredicate? The property might be noted as @objc ones. What about just `filter()` method of Swift Native Array and not NSArray?

Comment: yourArray.filter { $0.name.contains("dogname") }

Comment: `$0.name.range(of: "n", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil` instead since it's `CONTAINS[c]`, so case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @Larme in the comments, you should consider using Swifts `Array.filter()`.

However, if you want or must use `NSPredicate` for some reason, you could do so as well. Please note that the predicate is used to test each element in the array. Therefore, the keyPaths used in the predicate must be given with respect to the element.

Hence, the predicate must be:
`let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", text)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need NSPredicate, you can use filter directly on your array

```
let productSearchResults = array.filter { $0.name.contains(text) }
```

But if you really want to use NSPredicate, try:

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY name contains[c] %@", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `filter` function

```
 let filterArray = dogArray.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
```